# How to scale and align an image in an imageView

Tags: android

So to align an `imageView` with `layout_gravity` I **must** use `wrap_content`

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:background="@drawable/heart">
</ImageView>
```

But If I want to scale the image in the view, I can't use `layout_gravity` because I need to define `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

How can I scale **and** use `layout_gravity`?

**edit:** I answered my own question with this solution

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="right">

      <ImageView
           android:layout_width="10dp"
           android:layout_height="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/heart">
      </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_gravity` sets the `gravity` of your `ImageView` in its parent layout. It won't change even if change the size of the `ImageView`

Comment: `layout_gravity` only works when I set the height and width to wrap content

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your image view

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

and for more types of `scaleType` see [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

> ImageView is comes with different configuration options to support
>   different scaleTypes. scaleType options are used for scaling the
>   bounds of an image to the bounds of this view.

```
 <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/heart"
         android:scaleType="center"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true">
    </ImageView>
```

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to use `wrap_content` even if you set `layout_gravity`.

> layout_gravity only works when I set the height and width to wrap content

Try to set the parent ViewGroup's width to `match_parent` to expand it full width.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/heart" />
</FramaLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `wrap_content`, your `ImageView` takes the size of the image. The `layout_gravity` won't change by changing the `imageView` size. use `android:scaleType="fitEnd"` for changing the image alignment

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. I had to nest the image view inside a parent layout, using `gravity` not `layout_gravity`

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="right">

     <ImageView
          android:layout_width="10dp"
          android:layout_height="10dp"
          android:background="@drawable/heart">
     </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is same to set `layout_gravity="right"` to ImageView instead of the parent ViewGroup's `gravity="right"`.